# Magento 2 Knockout Js Checkbox Checked

Tags: magento2.3

I want to preselect the checkbox based on the data but checkbox are not getting preselected not sure why.

Below is the code.

Knockout

```
 salesPerson: ko.observableArray([
                { itemName: 'Choice 1' ,checked:true },
                { itemName: 'Choice 2' ,checked:false}
            ]),
 chosenSalesPersons: ko.observableArray()
```

HTML Code

```
 <div class="chechbox-wrap" data-bind="foreach: salesPerson,  event: { scroll: function(){} }">
                        <div data-bind="text: itemName"></div>
                            <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.chosenSalesPersons" />
                                <span></span></label>
                        </div>
```

Comment: if i change  to this it works  but my choosenSalesperson functionality gets affected <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: checked" />

Answer (score 0):

Just try replacing your code with below code:

```
      salesPerson: ko.observableArray([
            { itemName: 'Choice 1'},
            { itemName: 'Choice 2'}
        ]),
          chosenSalesPersons: ko.observable('Choice 1')
```

Comment: i want to show choice 1 as checked .this doesnt work

Comment: please check i have updates my answer